# Which logging pattern for LogBack in Spring Boot does indent messages with newline chars?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

LogBack as logger in Spring Boot uses a quite powerful and [sophisticated pattern language](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) to configure how logs should look like. Yet, I have not found how to get following configuration done: Some log messages report very detailed state. I would like to collect everything as one multi-line string and write that to the logs so that the lines are indented:

[image: Target logging]

To separately log lines of a message in a multi-threaded smells, because the message is not hold together:
[image: Current logging]

Comment: After having posted, I see that the images are not optimal, the log levels differ. I hope that my point is clear enough.